# Sentence from Pimsleuer

Tags: resource, online-resource

I was looking for some phrases to practice German. I'm studying it by some tools and I would like to be able to read that sentence again to avoid forgetting.

Do you know any website where I can find the sentence used by Pimsleur for example?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://quizlet.com/RedSeaHounds/folders/pimsleur-german-language-course) helps a little bit..

Comment: yes, it would be wonderful if it was bigger..

Comment: @FranzEbner: make your comment an answer so you can get the upvotes!

Comment: too small amount of sentences.. ;)

Answer (score 2):

How about [this link](http://www.pimsleurapproach.com/resources/german/articles/common-german-phrases/)? I believe it has a few more samples.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Why? No need for me to take credit for the work of others?